# Two column centered login screen with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have more or less got the login screen looking how i want.

Here is a link:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/parallax-login-form

However I would like to add a second column in alongside the login form. So on the left it would have the login form then on the right hand side it would have an area for some information.

Everything I add in for some reason puts the second column directly below the login form, whereas i want it alongside next to each other.

How is this possible?

Comment: Try `margin-left:0` for `.col-md-offset-4`

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add to both columns a

```
float:left;
```

within a container. The container needs to be

```
margin:0 auto;
```

to keep it centered.
within the container, at the end of it, you need a div with

```
clear:both;
```

Summarized:

```
<div class="container" style="margin:0 auto;width:300px;">
<div class="col1" style="float:left;width:150px;"></div>
<div class="col2" style="float:left;width:150px;"></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```